Occupation number doubt in QFT
Let say we have the Hamiltonian of a free scalar field in QFT:
$$\hat{H} = \mathcal{V}\int{\frac{d^3k}{8\pi^3}\hbar\omega_k\left(\hat{a}^\dagger_k\hat{a}_k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
The question is what would we get if we ask for the expectation value of "$|n\rangle$". In occupation number notation:
$$|[n_\alpha]\rangle = |n_1, n_2,...,n_\alpha,...\rangle$$
Meaning that there are $n_\alpha$ in the state $|\alpha\rangle$. Now it is straightforward notation that $|0\rangle = |0,0,0,...\rangle$ and thus:
$$\langle 0|\hat{a}^\dagger_k\hat{a}_k|0\rangle = 0 \forall k$$
But if we multiply by $|n\rangle$, is it the same than to multiply by $|n\rangle=|n,n,n,...\rangle$?
$$\langle n|\hat{a}^\dagger_k\hat{a}_k|n\rangle = n \forall k$$
Is this correct? I feel it means that we have $n$ particles homogeneously in every mode $k$, and it does not feel natural or realistic. If that is wrong, how would the integral look like? Should we rather use the Bose-Einstein distribution?
$$\langle n_k|\hat{a}^\dagger_k\hat{a}_k|n_k\rangle = n_k = \frac{1}{e^{\beta\left(\hbar\omega_k - \mu\right)} - 1}.$$

Why do you think that $x|0\rangle=|x\rangle$??? Inside ket is the name/index of the state, while the prefactor is an amplitude of the state. It has to do with basic QM, not QFT.

@RogerV. where did I assume $x|0\rangle = |x\rangle$? Do you mean that it is not possible to have $|n\rangle = |n, n,…\rangle$?

I am talking about this sentence: But if we multiply by $|n\rangle$, is it the same than to multiply by $|n\rangle=|n,n,n,...\rangle$?

@TobiasFünke well I am not sure I understand it fully and that is why I ask the question. My doubt is if you should get the expectation value by using $|n\rangle$ or $|n_k\rangle$. I assume it is the latter and the former is just a non-realistic, special case but I wanted confirmation. I also wanted to know what distribution would $n_k$ have if it is not constant.

@RogerV. yeh I think it doesn’t make sense and should use $|n_k\rangle$ instead. That is what the question asks, as well as what $n_k$ would be if it is not a constant $n$.

@TobiasFünke wait, can you have $|n_k\rangle = |n_1, n_2, …\rangle$ with all $n_k>0$? Would then the integral with creation and annihilation operators diverge?

I retracted my close vote and posted an answer... hopefully, I now understand the question correctly.

@TobiasFünke Maybe another way of rephrasing the question is if the integral with $\hat{n}_k$ diverges just as the integral for the zero-point energy with $1/2$ does. If you did not have the zero-point energy (i. e., you replace $1/2$ with $0$) would the integral diverge? I guess it does not, but that’s what I am not sure about.

Sorry. I still don't understand. Let me rephrase my comments: How do you define the vector $|n,n,n,n,\ldots\rangle$ (for infinitely many single-particle states)?

@TobiasFünke basically that vector means that there are $n$ particles for mode 1, there are $n$ particles for mode 2, and so on for all modes. If the notation used is wrong I’ll be glad if you correct it. Also I’d like to know if that is realistic, because having more than zero particles in a really high mode (which entails a lot of energy) seems unrealistic.

I removed/ retract my comments because I don't really understand what you mean, and hence I cannot give a concrete comment on that. So just forget what I've said.

Every position in a wave function/state vector corresponds to a mode - that is to a specific value of index $k$ in $a_k, a_k^\dagger$. In this sense, writing $|n_1,n_2,...\rangle$ is confusing, since labels of the occupation numbers have the same indices as the respective states. However, operator $a_1$ always acts on the first position in the state vector, regardless of the label for its occupation number:
$$
a_1|n_1, n_2,...\rangle=\sqrt{n_1}|n_1-1, n_2,...\rangle,\\
a_1|n_2, n_1,...\rangle=\sqrt{n_1}|n_2-1, n_1,...\rangle,\\
a_1|n, n,...\rangle=\sqrt{n_1}|n-1, n,...\rangle
.
$$
Thus, for an arbitrary mode $k$:
$$
\langle n, n,...|a_k^\dagger a_k|n,n,..\rangle = n.
$$
Note that we are just talking about basis states here - no assumption is made about the system being in a thermodynamic state. If we do apply thermodynamic averaging, and the particles are fermions, then
$$
\left[a_k^\dagger a_k\right]=\text{Tr}_{(n_1,n_2,...)} \langle n_1,n_2,...|Z^{-1}e^{-\beta H}a_k^\dagger a_k|n_1,n_2,...\rangle=\\
\sum_{n_1}\sum_{n_2}...\sum_{...}
\langle n_1,n_2,...|Z^{-1}e^{-\beta H}a_k^\dagger a_k|n_1,n_2,...\rangle
$$
In case of non-interacting particles, the sum splits into a product of sums
$$
=\prod_k \sum_{n_k}\langle n_k |Z_k e^{-\beta \epsilon_k n_k}a_k^\dagger a_k|n_k\rangle
$$
Thenen, for fermions $n_k=0,1$ and we obtain Fermid-Dirac statistics (with an appropriate normalization), wheras for bosons $n_k=0,1,2,...$ and the Bose-einstein distribution for every mode results.

Good answer. I did not know that you would get $\sqrt{n_1}$ from $|n_2, n_1, …\rangle$, but interesting to know.

This is how teh creation/annihilation operators are defined... though for fermions $\sqrt{n}$ is trivial and is not spelled explicitly. I also added a part regarding the statistics to my answer. No offense, but this is a textbook stuff - e.g, the introductory chapters of Mahan, Fetter&Walecka or the QFT book that you are using.

To mark your answer, could you include if you should get the expectation value of the $\hat{n}_k$ term by using $|n\rangle = |n, n,…\rangle$ or rather it is more appropriate to use $|n_k\rangle = |n_1, n_2,…n_k\rangle$ as a general case?

Yeh ok you did add a response to that.
